# Formula that describes the movement of a bishop in chess

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, regression

I'm programming a chess game and I'm trying to validate the movements every player tries to make. Obviously, every piece can move differently and I've had no trouble validating their moves up until now.

The first thing I do in order to validate the pieces is to check for collisions. In order to achieve that, I calculate the squares that are in between the original position of the piece and the final destination and check if there are any pieces in those squares.

Each position in the board has two values: x and y. So if I wanted to move the following bishop from `(1,4)` to `(4,1)` the squares in between would be `(3,2),(2,3),(1,4)`.

[image]

According to a [regression tool](http://www.mathportal.org/calculators/statistics-calculator/correlation-and-regression-calculator.php) I've used, the formula would be `y = 5 − 1⋅x`.
However that doesn't apply in other cases that follow the same pattern (where the bishop moves down-right) and it also doesn't apply in cases that don't follow the same pattern (for instance when the biship moves down-left).

So my question is, **how can I mathematically (or programmatically) obtain positions a bishop will have to go through in order to reach a certain destination?**

Comment: By the way, just a programmers' note: Any time you are doing a case statement on an enum, you are probably doing something wrong. Depends on the language, but here, just create a "step direction" object, `StepDirection(dx,dy)` and your move is some number of steps from a starting point in a direction. You could reuse that logic for rook and queen movements, too, since they have similar behavior. So you have a move being a step direction plus a number of steps. Then it is easy to compute the sequence of steps in between as one piece of code, not a horrible case statement.

Comment: Basically, your code is violating a prime rule: "DRY=Don't Repeat Yourself."

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I do know the code I posted is very inefficient but in order to make it better (or actually work for starters) I needed the help of someone who could help me break down the math and replace that horrible select with a single line formula.

Comment: The problems you get by violating DRY are not inefficiency, they are long term maintenance. Having similar code in lots of places makes it hard to change, hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a bishop is traveling from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$. This move is legal on an empty board if you have that:

$$|x_2-x_1|=|y_2-y_1|>0$$

Call this value $n$. and let $x_d=\frac{x_2-x_1}{n},y_d=\frac{y_2-y_1}{n}$. You have $x_d=\pm 1,y_d=\pm 1$, and together $(x_d,y_d)$  represents the "direction" of a single step in the move.

Then you have to check if $(x_1+kx_d,y_1+ky_d)$ is occupied for $1\leq k<n$.

This is essentially a "vector" formula: $(x_1,y_1)+k(x_d,y_d)$.

In your case, $x_1=1,y_1=4,x_2=4,y_2=1$ and $n=|x_2-x_1|=|y_2-y_1|=3$.

So $x_d=\frac{4-1}{3}=1, y_d=\frac{1-4}{3}=-1$ and your in-between squares are:

$$(1,4)+1\cdot(1,-1)=(2,3)\\
(1,4)+2\cdot(1,-1)=(3,2)
$$

You can just skip the fraction calculation, if you know the move is legal, and just define $x_d=\mathrm{sgn}(x_2-x_1), y_d=\mathrm{sgn}(y_2-y_1)$, where:

$$\mathrm{sgn}(z)=\begin{cases}1&z>0\\-1&z<0\\0&z=0\end{cases}$$

This is because, when $z\neq 0$, $\mathrm{sgn}(z)=\frac{z}{|z|}$.

If you must have a line formula, rather than a vector formula, define $m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$. By the above argument, we know $m=\pm 1$. Then $y = m(x-x_1)+y_1$ is the line, and you want to check the squares $(x,y)$ for $x$ strictly between $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your two downward cases, compared to the upward cases.  The upward cases -- which, you say, work -- start from the piece's location and move **towards** the target location.

In this case, **there is no reason** to deviate from listing your positions starting nearest the start position `PrePosition` and moving towards the target position `PostPosition`.

Comment: In the downward cases the `postPosition.Y > prePosition.Y`, thats why I reversed the order.

Comment: Is or is not prePosition always the location where your piece starts the move?

Comment: Yes, and it might be the case that a piece is moving 'back' (or 'forward' depending on the player).